# Sqldf join error though joining column present in both tables

Tags: r, sqldf

I am getting a peculiar error in sqldf, though I have used similar commands before. I have three packages loaded. The error is shown below. In my actual data frame, the error is same, even though the joining column, here X1, is present in both tables, has same data type. What mistake am I making ?

```
library("stringr") 
library("readxl") 
library("sqldf")

 q<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:7,20,rep=TRUE)))
 w<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:5,20,rep=TRUE)))

> q
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   3  6  4  0  7  4  1  1  0   4
2   5  3  2  1  7 


   > w 
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10

1   4  2  1  1  5  5  2  3  5   5
2   2  4  3  2  2  5 

 newdf<-sqldf("select * from q left join (select X3, X2,X4 from w) using (X1)")

    Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
      cannot join using column X1 - column not present in both tables
```

EDIT: The Desired output was the left join of the two tables, with table q being the left table.

Comment: Can you print out your `q` and `w` dfs? I suspect it is because those dfs don't have labels

Comment: they do have labels, can you try creating q,w at your end from commands above

Comment: your `select` statement from `w` __does not contain `X1`__, if you were to add `X1` to your `select` statement it would work. `sqldf("select * from q left join (select X1, X3, X2, X4 from w) using (X1)")`

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @bouncyball Please see the edit in the question and hopefully try to remove the hold on the question. I basically gave all the relevant information except a desired output, which was a simple straightforward join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to add X1 to:

```
(select X3, X2,X4 from w)
```

So that it is:

```
(select X3, X2,X4, X1 from w)
```

Here you're creating a table to be used in the merge, but you don't include in the column you need to merge on.